# OSL wave uv distort

Tags: osl

I'm new to OSL and trying to see an example of how someone would convert this unity shader to OSL in object space?
https://andreashackel.de/tech-art/stripes-shader-1/

```
Shader "Unlit/Stripes"
{
    Properties {
        _Color1 ("Color 1", Color) = (0,0,0,1)
        _Color2 ("Color 2", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
        _Tiling ("Tiling", Range(1, 500)) = 10
        _Direction ("Direction", Range(0, 1)) = 0
        _WarpScale ("Warp Scale", Range(0, 1)) = 0
        _WarpTiling ("Warp Tiling", Range(1, 10)) = 1
    }

    SubShader
    {

        Pass
        {
            CGPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag

            #include "UnityCG.cginc"

            fixed4 _Color1;
            fixed4 _Color2;
            int _Tiling;
            float _Direction;
            float _WarpScale;
            float _WarpTiling;

            struct appdata
            {
                float4 vertex : POSITION;
                float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
            };

            struct v2f
            {
                float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
                float4 vertex : SV_POSITION;
            };

            v2f vert (appdata v)
            {
                v2f o;
                o.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
                o.uv = v.uv;
                return o;
            }

            fixed4 frag (v2f i) : SV_Target
            {
                const float PI = 3.14159;

                float2 pos;
                pos.x = lerp(i.uv.x, i.uv.y, _Direction);
                pos.y = lerp(i.uv.y, 1 - i.uv.x, _Direction);

                pos.x += sin(pos.y * _WarpTiling * PI * 2) * _WarpScale;
                pos.x *= _Tiling;

                fixed value = floor(frac(pos.x) + 0.5);
                return lerp(_Color1, _Color2, value);
            }
            ENDCG
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sticking to the original as closely as possible:

```
shader Stripes(
    point UV = 0,
    float Scale_X = 10,
    float Scale_Y = 10,
    float Direction = 0,
    float Amplitude = 1,
    float Frequency = 1,
    color Color1 = 0,
    color Color2 = 1,
    output color Color = 0
)
{
    //Scaling
    float x = UV[0]*Scale_X;
    float y = UV[1]*Scale_Y;

    //Smeared 'Rotation'
    x = mix(x,y,Direction);
    y = mix(y,1-x,Direction);

    //Wave
    x += Amplitude * sin (Frequency * M_2PI * y);

    Color = (x-floor(x) > 0.5 ? Color1 : Color2);
}
```

This script returns a color, rather than a shader (a `closure`).. which would be strictly equivalent.

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much, really interesting to see! I'm intrigued by your comment about crunching it a bit more by doing the math differently. Would you mind sharing an example of what your thinking?

Comment: @simhod see edit.. I just remembered.. OSL's `mix()` is a `lerp()`.