# OSL Wavy line freq and thickness

Tags: osl

Could anyone show me how I create a wavey line like this in OSL and able to control the frequency and the thickness of the line? One line is nice but what about multiple waving lines too?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [OSL wave uv distort](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/205219/osl-wave-uv-distort)

Comment: Well yes and no, that answer distorted the UV's, I'm interested in learning how to draw a waving line without distorting the UV's. It also doesn't answer how to change the thickness of the lines themselves?